# Zend_View caching (Redis)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, redis, zend-view, zend-controller

**Task:**
During the process of action of Zend Application to achieve next:
- for each unique url or any definite url to substitute Zend_View object by data stored in the cache (Zend_View object ) and not to perform Action
- if data in cache is null, then to prerform Action and to set data in cache.

**Conditions**
- Changes mustn't be set in any Zend Controller (Action)
- init Action must be performed in any case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is register an action helper and use the `preDispatch` method to retrieve the cache. If a cache exists, you can set the dispatched flag to skip the action call.